# IF conditional statements formatted wrong?

Tags: java

should be ab easy one.  I have 3 checkboxes and have a multitude of conditional statements that should execute based on which checkboxes are entered.  In this case I have all 3 "checked"....so none of these statment should run.  It's looks like I formatted them wrong.  Let me know what I did wrong...thanx

logger:

```
 //  form.isOpenLevel() = true
  // form.isPhyCompLevel()  = true
  // form.isFinCompLevel()  = true
```

These three statements should only execute if 2 out of the 3 are true.  At least thats what I was trying to do.

```
 if ((form.isOpenLevel() == true && form.isPhyCompLevel() == true) && (form.isFinCompLevel() != true));
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("MSST_HEADER_DATA_MV.FIN_COMP_DATE","is","NULL"));

        }


        if ((form.isPhyCompLevel() == true && form.isFinCompLevel() == true) && (form.isOpenLevel() != true));
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("MSST_HEADER_DATA_MV.PHYS_COMP_DATE","is","NOT NULL"));

        }

        if ((form.isOpenLevel() == true && form.isFinCompLevel() == true) && (form.isPhyCompLevel() != true));
        {
            paramBean.addFilter(new DetFilterCriteriaBean("nvl2(MSST_HEADER_DATA_MV.PHYS_COMP_DATE,MSST_HEADER_DATA_MV.FIN_COMP_DATE,'X')","is","NOT NULL"));

        }
```

Comment: remove semicolons after `if()`

Comment: Try removing `;` after `if`—it helps.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies...I cant believe i didnt notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the extra paranthesis are redundant:

```
((a && b) && c)
```

is equivalent to

```
(a && b && c)
```

Also - "These three statements should only execute if 2 out of the 3 are true" means

```
if ( b && c )
```

should be enough.

Finally, the semicolons after the `if` is ending the conditional:

```
if ( b && c );
   statement;
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( b && c )
{
}
statement
```

That's why your statements always execut.

Remove the `;` after the conditions.

Comment: thanks for the info man...for some reason i didnt notice the semicolons

Comment: @DocHoliday glad to help. You should also take into account the rest of the notes. `((a && b) && c` might make other programmers reviewing your code giggle, and an extra condition in the clause can reduce performance.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the semi-colons on the IF lines.

The semi-colons are essentially saying to Java "DO NOTHING".  Notice these are equivalent:

```
if (complex-logic) ;

if (complex-logic) { /* DO NOTHING */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of your if statement.  This preemptively closes it.

In other words, this:

```
if (a); {
   //do something
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if (a) {
}

{
  //do something
}
```

In which case `//do something` becomes a floating block which is always run, and the conditional part of your if statement has no code to run.

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolons at the end of your `if` statements; Remove them. You're ending the conditional right there - the blocks enclosed in the curly braces are being executed *outside* the conditionals.

In addition, you don't need to check for equality; your methods are returning `boolean` values which you can evaluate directly:

```
if ( form.isOpenLevel() && form.isPhyCompLevel() && !form.isFinCompLevel() )
{
    ...
}
```